# How to get URL to download latest built artifact package in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-artifacts, azure-packaging

I used to have a simple URL like this (below) that automatically point to the latest build artifact.

```
https://{organization}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_packaging?_a=packagefeed={feedid}&package={packageid}&preferRelease=true?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

But it doesn't work anymore due to some update by Azure.

Does anyone know a way to get around this?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to download the artifact published by the [**Publish Build Artifacts task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) or [**Publish Pipeline Artifacts task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops) from the build pipeline, you can use the RESI API "[**Artifacts - Get Artifact**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts/get-artifact?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)" to get the download URL the specified build artifact.

If you want to get the download URL of a package published to the feed of Azure Artifacts, you can try using the following RESI API to download the package:

- "[**Maven - Download Package**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifactspackagetypes/maven/download-package?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1)" to download a Maven package from the feed of Azure Artifacts.
- "[**Npm - Download Package**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifactspackagetypes/npm/download-package?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1)" to download a Npm package from the feed of Azure Artifacts.
- "[**NuGet - Download Package**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifactspackagetypes/nuget/download-package?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1)" to download a NuGet package from the feed of Azure Artifacts.
- "[**Python - Download Package**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifactspackagetypes/python/download-package?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1)" to download a Python package from the feed of Azure Artifacts.